# Asking someone to name every thing in the list using "Which"

Tags: sentence-construction

Here in Urdu, if I have to ask someone about naming all the books one have read (in say last 2 months), I will ask something which roughly translates to:

*"Which which books have you read in last 2 months?"*

What will be correct English statement for this?

Answer (score 2):

- After you have edited the question, I have to say that if you want to ask someone to list the books they have read, you can say **What books have you read in the last two months?**

Comment: So alone _Which books have you read_ will do?

Comment: Ok . see the answer.

Comment: Yes I got you - Thanks for clarifying my confusion.